# Selecting record based on TIMESTAMP column in oracle

Tags: sql, sql-timestamp, oracle-apex-23

I have the table contains column create_datetime.It is timestamp(6) data type.

I used the below query to fetch the create_datetime-15 days records

The table having records for this condition But it is not listing for below query

```
SELECT create_datetime 
FROM xy
WHERE create_datetime <= create_datetime-15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the units of the subtraction:

```
create_datetime - NUMTODSINTERVAL(15, 'DAY')
```

Comment: i tried this one .SELECT create_datetime 
FROM xy 
WHERE create_datetime <=create_datetime - NUMTODSINTERVAL(15, 'DAY')

Comment: it is not fetching records

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT create_datetime 
FROM xy
WHERE create_datetime <= DATE_SUB(create_datetime, INTERVAL 15 DAY);
```

Let me know if this help you!